# IIS 8.5 Custom Error Page failed to redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, iis-8.5

I configured the 404 error to redirect(302) client to a page instead of returning 404 error.
It is working, but I found once the reqest URL contains '%20' in URL, then the redirect will not function. IIS will return 404 to client.

I've also tried adding the same redirect setting into the ".NET Error Page" with no luck. Still failed and showed the 404 page.

Anyone has solution?

Win2012R2, IIS8.5, Microsoft .NET Framework :4.0.30319; ASP.NET :4.0.30319.34209, MVC4

Comment: I've tried to add the setting into IIS Error Page and .NET Error Page. But all don't work on %20 case. Since I've added code into BeginRequest and confirmed it doesn't enter BeginRequest before IIS decided to answer client with 404 error page.